# Unexpected identifier in definition. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token

Tags: f#

I'm currently trying to set up Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application so I can scan word documents for particular words and replace them.

Here is a part of my code that is not working.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application() { Visible = true };
```

It gives this error:

> Unexpected identifier in definition. Expected incomplete structured
>   construct at or before this point or other token.

```
let fileName = Path.Combine(
                  System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, 
                  "document.docx");


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application() { Visible = true };

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document aDoc = 
wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, "ReadOnly: false, Visible: true");

aDoc.Activate();`enter code here`

FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{id}", "12345");
```

Comment: Since your code has C# embedded, it's likely that you're brand-new to F#. I recommend reading through some tutorials on F# basics. This is a good place to start: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-in-60-seconds//

Answer (score 2):

Many parts of your code are using C# syntax, not F#. This is what it should look like written in F#:

```
let fileName = Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "document.docx")

let wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(Visible = true)

let aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, "ReadOnly: false, Visible: true")

aDoc.Activate()

FindAndReplace(wordApp, "{id}", "12345")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @TheQuickBrownFox however your solution produces 4 new errors.                                                                                          let wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application(Visible = true) -- 'new' cannot be used on interface types. Consider using an object expression '{ new ... with ... }' instead.

Comment: let aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName, "ReadOnly: false, Visible: true")          This expression was expected to have type
    'obj ref'    
but here has type
    'string'

Comment: aDoc.Activate() Unexpected identifier in definition. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Comment: Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.